# Cubase Drum Mapping

Tags: midi, cubase

I currently have a FAMEDD-502 and I can't set the notes on the module. I want to assign the hi-hat pedal to be a second drum bass kick and I use EZDrummer connected to Cubase. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does the HH pedal even send note messages, or just controllers?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer is NOT for EZDrummer, but **Superior Drummer 2**. I'll leave it here because it is closely related.

Yes, in fact this should not be very difficult:

1. Open EZDrummer and go to the "Construct" area
2. Select the drum you want to trigger (in the kit, you can see the setting panels change as you select different drums)
3. Click the learn button and step on the hihat pedal
   (4. if you want to control subpads, i.e. alternate sounds or articulations of that given drum/cymbal, make sure you select the right articulation)

[image]

Of course this assumes you already hooked up the midi controller in cubase and set that up as input to the instrument/midi channel

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Superior Drummer which has a neat "learn" function, you need to set this up using the Cubase Drum Map editor.

Most of EZDrummers map is GM compatible, which means that a GM map is a good start.

Notice the I-Note and O-Note columns - here you can use a different input note to trigger another output note:

[image]

Along with this EZDrummer chart you should be able to figure out where to put things:

[image]